# Existem outras linguagem de baixo nível sem ser Assembly?

Tags: característica-linguagem, assembly

Existem outras linguagem de baixo nível sem ser Assembly? LISP não é (eu acho) nem Fortran..

Linguagem de baixo nível seria língua mais próximas do binário, assim como o Assembly, língua que trabalha diretamente com os registros do hardware..
De alto nível seria próximo ao inglês

Comment: Linguagem de máquina está ainda abaixo de *assembly*, e de todo modo "assembly" não é bem uma linguagem - já que cada plataforma possui seu próprio código de montagem. FOTRAN é de mais alto nível que assembly, porém mais baixo do que C por exemplo (e esse mais baixo que muitas outras). E se me perguntar, diria que não existe linguagem de mais **alto** nível que Lisp... :P (Lisp é praticamente "matemática executável")

Comment: @mgibsonbr não respondeste a pergunta ;)

Comment: Não percebi o -1

Comment: Defina linguagem de baixo nível. Sua interpretação pode ser diferente da minha.

Comment: @bigown equivalente a Assembly.

Comment: @JorgeB. o autor, não você :)

Comment: Eu sei, mas pela pergunta dá para perceber @bigown :P

Comment: Eu não acho não. Eu acho que dá para responder mas a pergunta não está clara. P/ os padrões do SOpt ele pode estar ótima, mas p/ os padrões do que sempre foi usado na SE falta informações relevantes para responder condizentemente. Não estou reclamando da pergunta, muito menos de quem respondeu, eu poderia ter feito o mesmo, mas ela poderia ser bem mais informativa para evitar ambiguidade. Se ele der uma definição que bate com a minha, eu tenho uma boa resposta. Se ele confirmar o que você entendeu, então a do Miguel já está boa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Se eu tivesse uma resposta, eu responderia, não comentaria... :P Apenas quis ilustrar que dividir as linguagens entre "baixo nível" e "alto nível" é complicado, existe todo um espectro que vai desde "100% em conformidade com a arquitetura por baixo" até "100% abstrata". Pode-se traçar uma linha (como era feito antigamente) e dizer que "se é compilado/interpretado, é de alto nível" mais isso só reforça o mito que toda linguagem de alto nível é equivalente.

Comment: Cartão perfurado.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Linguagem de Máquina

É a linguagem que a CPU entende, composta por uma sequência binária, cujas regras são definidas por cada arquitetura.

O recomendável é gerar através de um compilador de outra linguagem de mais alto nível,
mas você pode abrir um editor hexadecimal, e pode escrever tudo usando caracteres `0123456789abcdef`, o que não é muito prático.

Depois você vai precisar de uma forma de carregar o código na memória, a não ser que você escreva também os bytes do executável e já salve como `.exe`.

A manutenibilidade é baixíssima, além de ser impossível comentar o código.

### Máquinas de Turing - Linguagens esotéricas

Outras alternativas, seriam implementações de [máquinas de Turing](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Turing) básicas. Existem várias linguagens:

- [Brainfuck](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck): essa é de lascar qualquer crânio humano... é uma linguagem minimalista, Turing-Complete e portanto é capaz de fazer tudo que qualquer outra linguagem é capaz de fazer.

  Exemplo da Wikipedia - Programa *"Olá Mundo!"*:

  ```
  ++++++++++[>++++++++>+++++++++++
  >---------->+++>++++++++>+++++++
  +++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++>+++
  ++++++++>+++<<<<<<<<<<-]>-.>--.>
  ++++.>++.>---.>---.>.>.>+.>+++.,
  ```

  Interpretador online (vai no google e digita [`online brainfuck interpreter`](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=online%20brainfuck%20interpreter)):

  - http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html
  - http://copy.sh/brainfuck/
  - http://www.iamcal.com/misc/bf_debug/
  - http://brainfuck.tk
- [Piet](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/): a linguagem é programada através de um Bitmap... então há muitos editores.

  Exemplo - testar se um número é primo:

  [image: teste de número primo em Piet]

  [Rode online o exemplo acima](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/npiet-execute.php?target=nprime.gif&input=11&go=1&internal=1)
- [Outras linguagens esotéricas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language): as linguagens acima, são as que achei mais interessantes mas existem outras. Esse link da WikiPedia possui uma listagem, que inclui as anteriormente apresentadas.

### Linguagem de descrição de hardware (LDH ou HDL em Inglês)

[Linguagem de descrição de hardware](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_hardware) são usadas para modelar o funcionamento de um hardware, partindo do princípio que este é feito usando portas lógicas, ao invés de instruções interpretadas por uma CPU.

Essas linguagens podem ser rodadas e depuradas como qualquer outra, através de uma simulação das portas lógicas, do fluxos de carga nos semicondutores, que no final das contas alteram DDPs e essas finalmente são interpretadas como sinais 1 e 0, ligado/desligado, etc..

Há nesse grupo de linguagens, aquelas de mais baixo nível e de mais alto nível.

Exemplo da wikipedia: [VHDL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL)

```
cmp : process
 begin
    if A = B then
       C ⇐ 0;
    else
       C ⇐ 1;
    end if;
 end process cmp;
```

Comment: Achei muito interessante a sua resposta +1 :)

Comment: Dá pra colocar comentários num programa escrito em hexadecimal se colocar *"jumps"* nos locais corretos. Sinceramente não entendo porque tem gente que prefere linguagem de alto nível se dá pra fazer tudo usando código binário... :p

Comment: @utluiz Eu havia pensado nisso, mas ai teria de haver um editor especializado pra traduzir isso `436f6d656e74e172696f` nisso `Comentário`... se bem, que agora que to lembrando, que quase todos os HexEditors possuem visualização HEX e também ASCII, então daria pra simular um comentário nesse editor.

Comment: @utluiz HUahua... eu também não consigo entender isso. O código já sai ofuscado, o que é uma enorme vantagem pra empresas que querem proteger o código. =P

Comment: @MiguelAngelo codigo em hexa != de ofuscado rs

Comment: @VitorCaleffi O conceito de ofuscado depende da habilidade de quem está lendo o código. Provavelmente código de máquina, em hexa ou qualquer outra base, vai além da capacidade e paciência da maioria das pessoas. Foi isso que eu quis dizer.